# C++ for-range loop

Tags: c++

I was playing with range loops, eg:

```
for (auto i : range) {
```

which is equivalent to

```
auto it = range.begin();
auto i = *it;
```

but what i want is this:

```
for (auto it : range) {
    *it; // the it var is not derefernced by range loop
```

is there a way to accomplish this?
maybe something like:

```
for (auto it : make_range(range)) {
    *it; // the it var is not derefernced by range loop
```

....

One solution I found so far is using boost::irange, eg:

```
for (auto it : irange(range.begin(), range.end())) {
```

Comment: Why not just use an ordinary `for` loop if you want actual iterators?

Comment: yes, but it wouldn't be pretty; `make_range` would have to return a wrapper that produces proxy iterators (see boost::iterator) that yield the backed iterator when dereferenced.

Comment: @vladr that's what i came up with pretty much ... wondered if there was cleaner way to do so

Comment: @Anycorn: That *is* the clean way to do it.

Comment: Kerrek's question still stands. Syntactic sugar is not really an answer, syntactic sugar is telling the container that you want to iterate over the elements, not using the iterators. Why do you need the iterators?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas well, i need to find an index of an object and have the object too - st less variables floating around.  with iterators i can make it one

Comment: @Anycorn: `std::find(c.begin(),c.end(),value)` will give you the iterator then. Or if you really want to loop, `for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it )`. If you have a vector and your type does not overload `operator&`, you can also do `for (auto &o : range) { pos = &o - &range.front(); }` (last one is ugly)

Answer (score 4):

The whole purpose of a for-range loop is to iterate through the contents of a container.  So no, there is no native means to gain access to the iterator used by the loop.  If you need that, you should not be using a for-range loop to begin with.  The only option to gain access to a container iterator in a for-range loop is to write a custom adapter class that wraps the container and exposes its own iterators that return container iterators when dereferenced. Then you iterate through the adapter instead of the container directly.